# What is __VMKLNX__ in Linux header files?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, predefined-variables, predefined-macro

In a lot of Linux kernel modules (hardware drivers) their source header files, one can spot lines like:

```
#ifndef __VMKLNX__
```

`__VMKLNX__` is not defined in the source code of this module. A guess is that `__VMKLNX__` is a "C" system specific predefined macro. Maybe related to virtual machines or even VMware. However I can't find any authoritative source to confirm this.

What is and how/where can I find the meaning of this `__VMKLNX__` part?

Comment: I would guess it stands for "virtual memory", since Linux also supports systems without an MMU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means the driver supports being built for the [VMware ESX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ESX) kernel, whose documentation and source code are not public.  The VMware ESX kernel is a hypervisor commonly called "vmkernel".  You can infer what `__VMKLNX__` is for by looking at code comments in existing drivers, like in *bnx2.c*:

```
#if defined(__VMKLNX__)
/* On VMware ESX there is a possibility that that netdev watchdog thread
 * runs before the reset task if the machine is loaded.  If this occurs
 * too many times, these premature watchdog triggers will cause a PSOD
 * on a VMware ESX beta build */ 
#define TX_TIMEOUT  (20*HZ)
#else
#define TX_TIMEOUT  (5*HZ)
#endif /* defined(__VMKLNX__) */
```

VMware ESX isn't linux, though.  The ESX kernel just implements an interface that allows it to run Linux device drivers.